# Difference between SPE and SPNE in Game Theory

Tags: definition, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am slightly confused as to what the difference between Subgame Perfect Equilibrium and Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium is.

I was told there is a difference, but now I found many lecture notes that use the terms as substitutes.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: All subgame perfect equilibria are Nash equilibria, but not vice versa. Check if your notes were discussing SPE vs NE.

Comment: I really mean SPE and SPNE.  But I got you, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The two terms, SPE and SPNE, refer to exactly the same equilibrium concept in game theory, i.e. a strategy profile that induces a NE in every subgame.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgame_perfect_equilibrium):

> In game theory, a **subgame perfect equilibrium** (or **subgame perfect Nash equilibrium**) is a refinement of a Nash equilibrium used in dynamic games. A strategy profile is a subgame perfect equilibrium if it represents a Nash equilibrium of every subgame of the original game.